# Excel Export: How to export JSON data to Excel from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel

I have developed a web project in asp.net MVC 4 were registered user can generate Reports based on their Transaction. For report generation i am using JqGrid.

Currently all the reports are generating well and i want to add a feature 'Export to Excel' in my project.

Since my generated report is very large i dont want to send the entire date to server again for generating Excel.So i am planning to generate Excel from client Side.

So have done some research in web and i found one javascript library [here](https://github.com/btechco/btechco_excelexport/wiki) . I added this library in my project and it s working fine.But i found one problem here ,it wont work in IE(any version).

Is there any other javascript lib available so that i can export my report data to Excel.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From your link, under "features", it clearly says "Supported on all jQuery compliant browsers." - are you saying IE is not jQuery compliant? Or that their claim is inaccurate?

Comment: thanks for the comment @Floris.But under supported browsers they have not listed IE. Issue : https://github.com/btechco/btechco_excelexport/issues/10

Comment: Your js library uses a `data:` URI to perform the Excel export.  IE more restrictive than other browsers around what you're allowed to do with such URI's.

Comment: i believe this is close enough for me http://demos.w3lessons.info/jquery-table-export#

Answer (score 1):

Farther down in the page you'll see this:

**Supported Browsers:**

Chrome, supported in all versions
Firefox, supported in all versions
Opera, supported since 7.2
Safari, supported in all versions
***Internet Explorer, not compatible.***

This is because this plugin (battatech_excelexport) uses data URIs.
http://caniuse.com/datauri

Comment: What plugin uses data URIs? Your answer is not clear to me.

Comment: battatech_excelexport jQuery Plugin. (i edited my answer)

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend to you the datatableJS API .**

It is a faster and easy Javascript API (client side) that can you do HTML tables and easy export to

- EXCEL(XLSX,CSV)
- PDF
- Print
- Clipboard

you will found more information here:

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

and if you want to export the data formated as text, you need to follow that steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36142043/4241058

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I forgot say that it works cross browser (including in IE)

Answer (score -2):

The library code https://github.com/btechco/btechco_excelexport/blob/master/Scripts/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js does not seem to have anything that might hinder IE. However, though the wiki link says all jQuery compliant browsers, the **Supported Browsers** underneath does not have IE listed.

Can you share the version of the IE used. Maybe that can help.

Comment: I am using IE 10 .Please see this issue also, https://github.com/btechco/btechco_excelexport/issues/10